# How to get the last n files in a directory

Tags: c

I need help with getting the last 3 files in a directory.
I have an application that creates files in it and they have dates in the file names displayed as MMDD eg 0301.
There are a few files that have differents names but all have the dates on them and I'm new to C programming and don't know how to display only the last 3 file names. 
If someone could help me it would be really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to get _all_ files in a directory?

Comment: Open directory; read files one by one in an array; if array length is 4, sort array and delete last element; repeat until you read all the files; close the directory. Not very efficient since library provided quicksort and here you'd be far better served by a specialized insertion sort, but I think I/O times are going to dominate anyway.

Comment: You should start with `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or a variation thereof.

Comment: What do you mean by "last n files"?  Last by *what*?  Modification date?  Name? Size?

Comment: "why isn't this code working?" is not really a close reason for this question. There __is__ no code.

Comment: The file names are already sorted in descending order by date.Each day a new file is automatically created for that day as it is a point of sale terminal so all I need to do is keep that last 3 dates and remove the rest. So when a new date is created the oldest one will be deleted.

Comment: @DanielBasson what's wrong with the answer proposed below?y

Comment: Nothing, I only saw it afterwards. It definitely helped. Thanks

Comment: "The file names are already sorted". By whom? Unless you sort them yourself (and then you should already know how to answer your question), you will sooner or later get the files in an order you didn't expect. Be very aware that even though you might have gotten the files in some specific order in your limited testing there is nothing in most filesystems that guarantees any particular order of entries in a directory.

Comment: @Art iirc murder^Wreiserfs presents the directory entries lexicographically sorted as a result of the tree structure used.

Comment: They have been sorted so that the latest file in first because they have been sorted by date. It looks similar to this: 0301,0228,0227,0226

Comment: @DanielBasson By whom? Who does the sorting? When? If you yourself already do the sorting correctly then the question doesn't make sense since it's much more trivial than to correctly sort the directory entries. If you just assume that there is some sorting done because the directory entires happen to appear sorted right now, you are setting yourself up for a lot of pain.

Comment: My uncle who wrote the application did it. I'm just doing small tweaks here and there

Answer (score 3):

The typical and most robust way would be:

1. Read the contents of the directory into an in-memory array (see [`opendir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and friends if you're on POSIX)
2. Sort the array based on the filenames (using [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) of course)
3. Extract the three last elements

Of course this would be brittle if files can be created while you're doing this, that is typical for this kind of filesystem-inspection.

Comment: Why perform a sort (having a complexity of nlog(n)) ? He can simply maintain a priority queue of size 3 and it would be done in O(n).

Or in general case O( number_of_files * log(number_of_files_required))

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Because the gain in robustness by using long tested functions probably outweighs the minimal performance gain by far. But in theory, your approach is of course more appropriate.

Comment: you can refer to [link](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-list-files-directory/) on how to do opendir() and follow @unwind ans

Comment: Thanks for all your guys help I really appreciate it